# Send text into the Email text editor from a lightning component

Tags: email, aura, text, editor

I have to send a predefined text into the email text editor when the user clicks something (On the Case page).

It seems that there is no way to do it from an lwc component, but from an aura component I am able to at least get a handle of a component which is outside of mine through $A.getComponent(id). 
Although I don't have a stable id yet.

Or can I iterate through the elements from $A.root or $A.getRoot?
If I find the text editor finally, can I change its content?

Comment: can you add code snippet?

Comment: Not really, I don't have a working code snippet.
In the meanwhile we think that this can't be done through accessing the DOM.

Maybe with some kind of salesforce events, but I couldn't find anything.